# How to save file using Camera 2 api in android

Tags: java, android

using camera2 api i m save file like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <=Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                    final String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pikpap/";
                     file1 = new File(folderPath);
                } else{
                    file1 = new File( CameraFragment.view.getContext().getExternalFilesDir()+ "/Pikpap/");
                }
                if (!file1.exists()) {
                    file1.mkdirs();
                }
                String fullName = file1.getAbsolutePath() + "Pikpap" + currentTime+name + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(fullName);
```

but some time file not save  and image blank set on image view 
this issue created on all devices